# HTTP 400 Bad Request trying to create a bulk API job using RestTemplate

Tags: rest-api, java, bulk-api, sfrestrequest

Am trying to use spring RestTemplate to create a bulk API job. Below is the code

```
HttpHeaders headers= new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("sforce-enable-pk chunking","chunksize=10000");
headers.add("X-SFDC-Session","MYSESSIONID");

JSONObject jsonBody=new JSONObject();
jsonBody.put("operation","query");
jsonBody.put("Object","account");
jsonBody.put("contenttype","CSV");

HttpEntity<String> request=new HttpEntity<String>(jsonBody.toString,headers);
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory=new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory ();
InetSocketAddress inaddress=new InetSocketAddress("HOST",PORTNUMBER);
Proxy proxy=new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,inaddress);
factory.setProxy(proxy);

RestTemplate rt=new RestTemplate(factory);

try{
ResponseEntity<String> response=rt.exchage("URL",HttpMethod.POST,request,String.class);
}catch(RestClientException e){

}
```

The above code is failing with HTTP 400 Bad request. Please suggest,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
HTTP.Header['X-SFDC-Session'] := SalesForce_oauth_token['access_token'].Value;
HTTP.Open ('POST', '/services/async/38.0/job');
HTTP.Header['Content-Type'] := 'application/json';
HTTP.Header['Accept'] := 'application/json';
Cont_Object := TJSONOBJECT.Create
Cont_Object.AddString('operation','update');
Cont_Object.AddString('object','account');
Cont_Object.AddString('contentType','CSV');
```